# call IBOutlet UIButton from one class to another Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have one view controller called `dataviewcontroller`.Another view controller called `scopeviewcontroller`

In `dataviewcontroller` i have an `IBOutlet` of `UIButton` called `AddData`.I want to call this button in my `scopeviewcontroller`. And I want to hide that button.

I have used this view controller in my [pager](https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu). I want to hide `AddData` button in my `scopeviewcontroller` which is present at the third page.

I tried this code in `viewdidload` in my `scopeviewcontroller`.

But is m getting this error:  `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'AddData'`

my code in first view controller:

```
class dataviewcontroller: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var AddData: UIButton! 
}
```

**my second view controller:**

```
class scopeviewcontroller: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "data", bundle: nil)
       let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dataviewcontroller")

        controller.AddData.hidden = true

    }


}
```

Please help me out!...Thanks

Comment: Change this line let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dataviewcontroller") to et controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dataviewcontroller") as? dataViewController

Comment: You need to explicitly mention which class type it is. Otherwise, by default, it will take it as UIViewController.

Comment: Another word of caution. If you are instantiating viewController means you are creating new state object for view controller which has its own states for its elements. Now based on your requirement think.

Comment: @hybrid Dev checks out the answer below and let me know if you have any confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to access the button on every view controllers, which you added on the pager. You can hide the button on the `scopeviewcontroller` itself. with the help of `CAPSPageMenuDelegate`

In ScopeViewController, set the delegate of your pager.

```
fun viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   pageMenu.delegate = self 
}
```

And implement the protocol `CAPSPageMenuDelegate`

```
extension scopeviewcontroller: CAPSPageMenuDelegate {
    func willMoveToPage(_ controller: UIViewController, index: Int) {
        self.AddData.isHidden = (index == 2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Type Cast the `dataviewcontroller` from `UIViewController` because by default it will return to the parent class `UIViewController` object that doesn't have the `AddData` button, You have to do just like that:-

```
var needHideAddData = true

class scopeviewcontroller: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "data", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dataviewcontroller") as! dataviewcontroller
        controller.AddData.hidden = true
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

Basically, it will not be accessed before initialization the `UIViewController` nib so **after loaded the nib the references and the memory will be allocated** to the IBOutlet so you have only two way to implement that:

**1:-** By default you have to make it hidden and when you need unhide you can control in the `dataviewcontroller` `viewDidLoad` method.

**2** And the second one write code in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad` in dataviewcontrolleris like luckyShubhra tells:

```
class dataviewcontroller: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var AddData: UIButton! 
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.AddData.hidden = needHideAddData
    }
}
```

Comment: its forcing me to change from `hidden` to `isHidden` = true...but when i do like that...its crashing on that line

Comment: am getting only this `(lldb) `

Comment: but ia m not using any push or model seague to pass the view controller.. i am using ` let pageMenu: CAPSPageMenu! = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0.0, width:self.view.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)`..how do i pass the bool value in it

Comment: Simple, You can control bool by making global variable if you do not have any way to take decision in the `dataviewcontroller`

Comment: can u please explain in code example ...on how to do that global declare for that button in `dataviewcontroller `and how to call that in my `scopeviewcontroller`..it will be more helpfull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148753/discussion-between-salman-ghumsani-and-hybrid-dev).

Comment: Don't use ! anywhere in your code. Bad practice and it will lead to crashes. Use optional casting instead. `(viewController as? customViewController)?.customProperty`

Answer (score 0):

An outlet doesn't instantiate because an outlet is a variable (or property).

The objects in a nib are instantiated when that nib is loaded, and they are assigned to each outlet as immediately as possible afterward, after the objects are created but before awakeFromNib is sent to all relevant objects.

Check ans by Peter Hosey [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133931/when-does-an-iboutlet-initialize) for detailed explanation.

In your case you can pass a `bool` var from `scopeviewcontroller` to `dataviewcontroller`. Based on conditions you can set your `AddData` button hidden property true or false in `dataviewcontroller`'s `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.AddData.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Good explanation about ib outlets not being instantiated. Another alternative is to just programmatically create your button so that it is created on instantiation of your view controller. Do a `let button: UIButton = { return UIButton()}() inside of your custom view controller and you can access it that way.

Answer (score 0):

create object of dataviewcontroller in scopeviewcontroller. 
**eg. var dataVCObj = DataViewController();**
than using object dataVCObj you can access the iboutlet of button.
**eg. dataVCObj.AddData**

Comment: its crashing when i call like this in view did load 'dataVCObj.AddData.ishidden = true `