# Pass data from Table View Cell to a View Controller in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know this question is asked many time , i had searched a lot and tried many solution but not worked. I have made a customize table view in which data is load from a service. The data load is quite limited , i have to show the detail of data into new view controller when user click on a cell. Its should pass data of the respective cell which carries data. I have tried segue technique to pass data to new vc but fails , its shows null in value which i'm passing. I have created some labels in new vc in which i'm calling the values from table view cell. My code is,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
        //Do something
        ShowViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];


         destViewController.tites = [_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.prce = [_Price objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSLog(@"PPPP is %@",destViewController.phon);
         destViewController.ara = [_LandArea objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.phon = [_Phone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.citi = [_City objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.loc = [_location objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.tye = [_type objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.Idss = [_Id objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.nam = [_name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.emal = [_email objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.roomss = [_rooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.wash = [_washroom objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.flloors = [_floor objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.stat = [_status objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.descrp = [_descrip objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         destViewController.countryy = [_country objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this `prepareForSegue` method is being called? and this condition `isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"` is satisfied?

Comment: yes method is called and it moves to new vc but the values i'm passing are not going as i have NSLo some value but it shows null in front of them. @Mr.Bista

Comment: Take a note that you are printing phon variable before assigning to it...

Comment: Check my ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004596/call-iboutlet-uibutton-from-one-class-to-another-viewcontroller/45004745#45004745

Comment: An outlet doesn't instantiate because an outlet is a variable (or property). Check my ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004596/call-iboutlet-uibutton-from-one-class-to-another-viewcontroller/45004745#45004745

Comment: @HamzaImran why you use an array for every single attribute, is better approach use a model class to keep all those properties, also is easier to pass an object than a bunch of properties

Comment: how can i use model class? I'm new i don't know how to do it. @ReinierMelian

Comment: I have changed it and print the price value but it is null again. @Miknash

Comment: let me check it. @luckyShubhra

Comment: i want in objective c the link u provided is in swift. @luckyShubhra

Comment: ok.. get back to me if you can't get it.

Comment: I will add in Objective-C.

Comment: can you show me how to written code for trigger segue ?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:tableView];
}
 like this. @KKRocks

Comment: @HamzaImran please check if destViewController is nil...maybe there lies the problem

Comment: How it can be nil? @user1000

Comment: Actually first i have print the variable which i'm passing to new vc its coming null in same class and than again i have printed it in  new vc its null also there. @user1000

Comment: May be something was left out in storyboard, I'd suggest that you give hard coded values like destViewController.countryy = @"USA"; to check that if its still nil or not, Hope it helps

Comment: The data is coming from server and i'm first displaying it in table view where all the values are seen and than trying to pass it through segue method. @user1000

Comment: If its still nil then the problem lies in the values that you are assigning e.g [_country objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Have you checked by doing this destViewController.countryy = @"USA";

Comment: Price ,city area area and other values are coming in response its easily visible. @user1000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150088/discussion-between-user1000-and-hamza-imran).

Comment: waiting for u on chat. @user1000

Comment: Thanks a lot man u solved my issue, thanks for ur precious time. @user1000

Comment: can u join in discussion , i have some issue? @user1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in this question is that you are not populating the _Price and other arrays properly, so where you are populating _Title array , fill other arrays as well like _Price, _City

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your code :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:indexPath];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
 {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"])
      {
    ShowViewController *destViewController =(ShowViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
           NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
           destViewController.tites = [_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           destViewController.prce = [_Price objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           // use this indexpath for segue
      }
  }
```

Comment: what is mean't by use index path for segue? @KKRocks

Comment: did you got correct indexpath while asking the question ?

Comment: u r asking about the cell index path? @KKRocks

Comment: yes, using this code         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

Comment: yes its correct , when i click any cell it moves to vc . @KKRocks

Comment: can you check again this   [_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  and let me know is correct data or not ?

Comment: Actually when i run and load the table view it loads data from service and data is shown is each cell. and i had NSLog this destViewController.prc = [_Price objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSLog(@"PPPP is %@",destViewController.prc); but it shows null . @KKRocks

Comment: try to print this statement and let me know : NSLog(@"PPPP is %@", [_Price objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

Comment: its coming null. @KKRocks

Comment: it is the problem try my answer or print log of array in prepareForSegue.

Comment: in ur answer can u please explain how to send now values , give any one example so that i could try it. @KKRocks

Comment: i had tried ur answer but its again null . @KKRocks

Comment: wait i check again and let you know .

Comment: Have u checked it? @KKRocks

Comment: I'm waiting for ur response. @KKRocks

Answer (score 0):

An outlet doesn't instantiate because an outlet is a variable (or property).

The objects in a nib are instantiated when that nib is loaded, and they are assigned to each outlet as immediately as possible afterward, after the objects are created but before awakeFromNib is sent to all relevant objects.

In your case you can pass data in ShowViewController and update the label in ShowViewController's viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

Define string in ShowViewController interface as

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * titesStr;

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
     //Do something
     ShowViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
     destViewController.titesStr = [_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     ....
     ....
     ....
     }
}
```

In ShowViewController viewDidAppear update your label as

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];
      tites.text = titesStr;
 }
```

In place of passing data one by one you can use array also. Best implementation would be using model class.

EDIT

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:tableView];
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
     //Do something
     UITableView *tv = (UITableView*)sender;
     ShowViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tv indexPathForSelectedRow];
     destViewController.tites = [_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     ....
     ....
     ....
     }
}
```

Comment: destViewController.titesStr = [_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  its showing error that titesStr is not in ShowView Controller. @luckyShubhra

Comment: check this line [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:self];

Comment: sender should be self.

Comment: is your self.tableView globally declared??

Comment: ** destViewController.titesStr = [_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; its showing error that titesStr is not in ShowView Controller ** because in order to access titesStr from ShowViewController you need to create property of titesStr in interface file of ShowViewController i.e. .h file.

Comment: yup i have tried it by creating a property in ShowViewController and put the value of it in my label name title , and print the value which is coming in title but it is coming null. @luckyShubhra

Comment: is your self.tableView globally declared??

Comment: try NSLog(@"PPPP is %@",[_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); in your prepare for segue

Comment: is the above log prinitng any value

Comment: its coming null

Comment: I have updated my ans use this preapreforsegue and then print the value.

Comment: its again coming null

Comment: i don't know who did this seriously

Comment: No worried. What are you trying to print ??

Comment: NSLog(@"PPPP is %@",[_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

Comment: NSLog(@"PPPP is %@",[_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]); yes im printing this  and its showing null in front of PPPP is (null)

Comment: Clarify me tites, prce,ara,phon ,citi etc are defined as UILabels or NSString in your ShowViewController

Comment: have you tried passing indexpath of tableview as @KKRocks helped

Comment: Do show me where have you declared your UITableView

Comment: I'm trying answers of both of u one by one. In Show View Controller tites,prc,nam,emal,phon,citi etc are the  NSString and in same Show View Controller i have made outlets for labels like price,name,email etc these will take values from the NSString variables and i have printed them in viewDidLoad method . @luckyShubhra

Comment: if u can give me ur email id or skype id i can send u the class it would be better u understand it. @luckyShubhra

Comment: developershubhra@gmail.com

Comment: sent u check it, i'm waiting for ur response. @luckyShubhra

Comment: i m checking. You should check your web service. I don't think so its returning any value.

Comment: in your loadCustomerData  NSLog(@"RESULT %@ ", results); prints null value

Comment: you should consult your backend person.

Comment: what i should ask? @luckyShubhra

Comment: the values are coming right from url but values are not coming in _Pice array

Comment: NSLog(@"RESULT %@ ", results); what do you get

Comment: I got response from service like this 2017-07-25 18:26:34.084 PK.House[16866:2778381] RESULT (
        {
        bathrooms = 0;
        city = lahore;
        country = pakistan;
        "dealer_email" = "chwaqas_5@hotmail.com";
        "dealer_name" = waqas;
        "dealer_phone" = 923004411736;
        floors = 0;
        images = "10295020170204_122827.jpg";
        "land_area" = "1 Kanal";
      } l

Comment: what to do now? @luckyShubhra

Comment: m still getting null value

Comment: can u share NSLog(@"RESULT %@ ", results);

Comment: thanks a lot for ur help , i have resolve it. @luckShubhra