# How to access width and height of a UIView from another class?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using UIPresentationController to make a custom animation. I'm trying to make it so that when a button press segues to the next view controller that the presented view controller takes up the width of one of the UIViews in the previous view controller. What I need help with is how to access the width and height of the UIView from my UIPresentationController class.

In View Controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonView: UIView!

func width() -> CGFloat {
    return buttonView.frame.size.width
}

func height() -> CGFloat {
    return buttonView.frame.size.height
}
```

In Presentation Controller:

```
override func size(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer, withParentContainerSize parentSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {

    let vc = ViewController()
    return CGSize(width: vc.width(), height: vc.height())
}
```

The error I currently have is that when I return buttonView.frame.size.width or buttonView.frame.width it unexpectedly returns nil for an optional value. However, the width is not an optional value and doesn't return nil if I print it out. It doesn't let me access the variable to use outside of the view controller's scope. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you initialized the view controller, the iboutlet for the button has not been initialized yet. SO, when you call the width function, you are accessing a nil for a non optional property. Iboutlets are initialized when the nib is loaded.

Here's how to access a view from another view controller..

[call IBOutlet UIButton from one class to another Viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004596/call-iboutlet-uibutton-from-one-class-to-another-viewcontroller?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you for the response! So what do you need to do to load the nib? Is that just when the view is loaded? Also, by initialized do you mean when the vc object is instantiated? Additionally, if this makes any difference, the "let vc = ViewController()" code is called after the ViewController's view has already been loaded because it's getting ready to transition to the next view controller (the one that is the same size as buttonView)

Comment: Nibs are loaded when their corresponding VC's awakeFromNib() method is called. The "let vc = ViewController()" is creating a new instance of the vc object. Even though your current ViewController's view is loaded, you created a new viewController and are using the newly instanced viewController to access the uninitialized button.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. I checked out your link and I'm still a little confused on how to initialize the outlet. With CAPSPageMenuDelegate it looks like I can only access the outlet from another class in the func willMoveToPage(). However, I need to access it in my func size() in my presentation controller. Do you know a workaround to still be able to do that?

Comment: You need to have reference to the vc with the button in your presentation controller.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I figured it out. In my PresentationController I instantiated the view controller via storyboard id. Then I access a property in the vc that has a getter that returns the view's width. In the getter I have an if statement before the return statement checking if the view is loaded or not, and if it's not loaded then I load the view using loadView(). This way the view's width won't be a nil value because the view will technically be loaded behind the scenes.

Comment: I should also say that awakeFromNib() didn't work in this case just because I not only needed the outlet initialized, but I also needed the view loaded to retrieve the size of my customView, so that's why I ended up using loadView() in my subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: @conman sure, but that is very inefficient for just grabbing a button width

Answer (score 0):

In your subclass of UIPresentationController you can do something like:

```
if let myVc = presentingViewController as? MyCustomVc {
    let myViewWidth = myVc.myCustomView.frame.width
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. What I ended up doing was instantiating the vc in my subclass of UIPresentationController via Storyboard ID (let vc: ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController). I assume the optional binding would work too though, so thank you.